# Type hint for output of plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly, type-hinting, python-typing, plotly-express

If I have a function that returns a plotly express figure, what is the correct way of type hinting?

The figure is of type:
`<class 'plotly.graph_objs._figure.Figure'>.`

Should I type hint by separately importing plotly, and writing:
`-> plotly.graph_objs._figure.Figure` ?

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly 
 
long_df = px.data.medals_long()

fig = px.bar(long_df, x="nation", y="count", color="medal", title="Long-Form Input")
print (type (fig))

def plot_bar (df: pd.DataFrame) -> plotly.graph_objs._figure.Figure :
  fig = px.bar(long_df, x="nation", y="count", color="medal", title="Long-Form Input")
  return fig

plot_bar(long_df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of convention, but usually when people work with plotly `graph_objects`, they have the following import:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
```

This means you can replace `plotly.graph_objs._figure.Figure` with `go.Figure` so your type hinting is a little easier to read:

```
def plot_bar(df: pd.DataFrame) -> go.Figure():
  fig = px.bar(long_df, x="nation", y="count", color="medal", title="Long-Form Input")
  return fig
```